# Где хранится буфер обмена в bash?(ctrl+y/ctrl+u)

Tags: linux, bash

Меня интересует техническая часть вопроса, а именно где хранится скопированный текст, после того как нажал <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>. В переменной окружения? В специальном устройстве?

Comment: Говорят не в bash никакого буфера обмена. Используется тот, который есть под рукой. В графической оболочке X даже 3 буфера. В текстовой консоли свой буфер.

Comment: @Sergey меня интересует тот, что в текстовой консоли.

Comment: Которая не в окошке? Да никто не знает как это работает. В лучшем случае упоминается gpm, выделение, копирование, вставка мышью. И на этом всё. Никто уже не пользуется текстовой консолью. Вспомнил вот. В командной строке используется readline, Наверняка он и обеспечивает буфер обмена. Тогда почти наверняка всё хранится в памяти.

Comment: Но есть история команд в файле ~/.history вроде

Comment: @Sergey посмотрел в исходниках readline, действительно хранится в памяти. В массиве rl_kill_ring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В памяти того самого процесса bash, в котором это происходит. Более точно, этим не bash занимается, а библиотека readline, и содержимое этого буфера - часть её состояния.

Answer (score 0):

В какой консоли? В linux десятки консолей.

Я работаю в konsole в этой консоли <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> копирование. Использую буфер обмена `Clipman`.

У bash буфера обмена находится в внутри программы и доступ возможен только по  нажатию клавиш , есть также история команд `history`

Comment: Вы неправы. https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC17 kill и yank - аналог cut и paste. Мало того, там не один буфер, а кольцо.

Comment: @Netch Вопрос был про bash а не библиотеку Readline. Но действительно в bash есть небольшой буфер в режиме emacs можно удалить слово или строку и вставить Ctrl+Y а в режими Vi тоже можно удалить слово или строку и вставить в командном режиме клавиша 'p'

Comment: bash очень сильно завязан на  readline, слишком сложно разделять, поэтому это одно и то же.